# Null Pointer Exception in Adapter

Tags: java, android

My logcat is indicating a null pointer exception, and I don't know how to solve these null pointer exceptions.

Null Pointer exception in my adapter class:

```
  File dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/myImages/");

  int count=dir.list().length; 

  String[] fileNames = dir.list();
```

Check the above lines... that is a value returning null.

**My code:**

```
package ImageViewExample.ImageViewExample;

   import java.io.File;

   import android.R.string;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.Environment;
   import android.provider.MediaStore;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
   import android.widget.Gallery;
   import android.widget.GridView;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

    public class ImageViewExample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Cursor imagecursor, actualimagecursor;
    private int image_column_index, actual_image_column_index;
    GridView imagegrid;
    private int count;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      init_phone_image_grid();
     }
     private void init_phone_image_grid() {
      String[] img = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
      imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
     img, null,null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "");


     System.out.println("path"+managedQuery(MediaStore.Images
    .Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, null,null, MediaStore.Images
     .Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + ""));
      image_column_index =   
     imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
      System.out.println("index"+imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow
     (MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID));
      count = imagecursor.getCount();
      imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);

      imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImAdapterh(this));
      System.out.println("index"+this);
      imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,int position, long id) {
                          System.gc();
      String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    actualimagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
    proj,null,null, null);
       actual_image_column_index =   
    actualimagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                  actualimagecursor.moveToPosition(position);
                  String i = actualimagecursor.getString(actual_image_column_index);
                  System.gc();
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewImage.class);
                  intent.putExtra("filename", i);
                  startActivity(intent);
            }
      });
    }


   public class ImAdapterh extends BaseAdapter{

   File dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Pictures/");
   int count=dir.list().length; 
   String[] fileNames = dir.list();

    private Context mContext;

   public ImAdapterh(Context c) {
       mContext = c;
    }

      public int getCount() {
       return count;
      }

      public Object getItem(int position) {
       return null;
      }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
       return 0;
      }

   // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ImageView imageView = null;        


     for(String bitmapFileName : fileNames)
     {
          if (convertView == null) 
          {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
              imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
              imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(85, 85));
              imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
              imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);                   

              Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dir.getPath() + "/" +   
               bitmapFileName);
              System.out.println(dir);
              imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);  
           }else 
           {
           imageView = (ImageView) convertView;            

           }
   } 
       return imageView;
       }
      }}
```

**Logcat error:**

```
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  
start activity  
ComponentInfo{ImageViewExample.ImageViewExample/ImageViewExample
.ImageViewExample.ImageViewExample}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417): Caused by:   
java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
ImageViewExample.ImageViewExample.ImageViewExample$ImAdapterh.<init>
(ImageViewExample.java:71)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
ImageViewExample.ImageViewExample.ImageViewExample
.init_phone_image_grid(ImageViewExample.java:49)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at  
ImageViewExample.ImageViewExample.ImageViewExample.onCreate(ImageViewExample.java:36)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-04 01:41:31.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: What line gives you the error? It looks to me you're implying it is the last line, but if so then `dir` would be NULL, and then the middle one should also give a nullpointer. Maybe your `FILE` command is failing?

Comment: how to correct my file command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

The `list()` method of `File` can return `null`. From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29):

> Returns: An array of strings naming the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. **Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.**

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that the list() is the one which resulting error, which can be happen because there is no file inside that folder ( "/myImages/" )

To fix that you have to check if the folder is empty or not :

```
File dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/myImages/");
if(dir!=null &&dir.list()!=null)
{
 int count=dir.list().length; 
 String[] fileNames = dir.list();
 //...<REST OF THE CODE>
}else
{
  //do empty folder handler here.
}
```

or

```
File dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/myImages/");
if(dir.list()==null)
{
  dir.setList(new ArrayList());// IF LIST is null, create empty list.
}
int count=dir.list().length; 
String[] fileNames = dir.list();
//..<REST OF THE CODE> ..
```

Comment: public class ImAdapterh extends BaseAdapter{
       
 File dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/myImages/");
 if(dir!=null &&dir.list()!=null)
 {
  int count=dir.list().length; 
  String[] fileNames = dir.list();
  //...<REST OF THE CODE>
 }else
 {
   //do empty folder handler here.
 }

    int count=dir.list().length; 
    String[] fileNames = dir.list();

    private Context mContext;

Comment: now i am trying to implement your code..its indicate Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

Comment: try to format your code **(CTRL+SHIFT+F)**and see whether you have extra "{"

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized
 - The method setList(ArrayList) is undefined for the type File

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer exception will be raised when listing the contents or number of files of a directory that does not exist or one that you do not have permissions to.

Check the following:

1. If external storage access has been mentioned in the manifest.
2. If the directory whose files you want listed actually exists within the external storage.

Also post the stack trace and `logCat` outputs. That would also help people help you.

HTH,
Sriram